# Sphinxsearch - Switching from 'regular' index to distributed index - Does this alter sorting in any way?

Tags: sorting, indexing, sphinx, distributed

We recently did some research on how to speed things up a bit in sphinxsearch.

We found a great way to speed things up is to use a distributed index.

We ran real-life tests, and found that queries execute somewhere between 35-40% faster when a distributed index is used.

What I mean by distributed is basically our regular index, split up into 4 (the box hosting this index has 4 cores) via adding `AND id % 4/3/2/1 = 0` into each source, for each of the parts of the index.

FYI, id is our primary key / auto increment.

So what this should do instead of having one huge index is split it up into 4.

And then we just use index type = distributed + local .... local .... local .... local .... for a 'put all the parts together' index.

We did some quick testing, the same results come back... Only 35-40% faster :)

So, before we implement this site wide, we would like to know:

**Does switching to a distributed index like the one mentioned above impact sorting in any way?**

We ask this  because we use sphinx for a number of SEO related items, and we NEED to keep the order of the results the same.

I should also mention, queries, all query options, etc stay the same. Any and all changes were done on the daemon end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sorting should be unaffected. You suffer a bigger performance hit when using distribution indexes and high offsets. But the first few pages will be fine.

As far as I know the gotcha are using grouping/clustering and kill-lists. But if not using them, should be nothing to worry about.